# Why must parameter to uib-typeahead method be a key-value pair?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

Why do I need to place `$viewValue` in a key-value pair in the example below (which uses Angular 1.6.2 and Typescript)?

```
export class PageHeaderComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
    public template: string = `
    // ... other markup omitted
    <input type="text"
       name="search" 
       class="form-control text-field"
       placeholder="{{$ctrl.searchPlaceholder}}"
       ng-model="$ctrl.search"
       uib-typeahead="item for item in $ctrl.getItems({value: $viewValue})"
     />
   ...
   public bindings: any = {
    headerTitle: "<",
    showBackButton: "<",
    entityName: "<",
    addAction: "&",
    adding: "<",
    search: "=",
    searchPlaceholder: "<",
    getItems: "&"
  };
}
```

This `PageHeader` component is contained within a `LandingPage` component.  `getItems` is a method on the `LandingPage` controller.

```
export class LandingPageComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
    public template: string = `
    <div class="landing-page">
        <page-header 
            header-title="'Businesses'"
            add-action="$ctrl.showAddBusiness()"
            entity-name="'Business'"
            search-placeholder="'Search for a business'"
            search="$ctrl.search.name"
            adding="$ctrl.adding",
            get-items="$ctrl.getItems({value})"
            ></page-header>
   // ... other markup omitted
   `;

    public controller: any = LandingPageComponentController;
}

export class LandingPageComponentController {

  // ... Irrelevant details omitted 

   public getItems(value: {value}): Promise<string[]> {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(["one", "two", "three", "four"]);
      });
  }
}
```

If I simply pass `$viewValue` by itself (and change the signature of `getItems` to `getItems(value: string)`, I get this error:

`TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '$ctrl' in o`.

Obviously, was able to fix the error, I just would like to understand why my fix worked.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't to do with `uib-typeahead`, but with the use of the Output Event binding ('&') between `LandingPageComponent` and `PageHeaderComponent`.

---

You can actually simplify your code a little bit:

In `LandingPageComponent` template:

```
get-items="$ctrl.getItems(value)"
```

In `LandingPageComponentController`:

```
public getItems(value: string): Promise<string[]> {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(["one", "two", "three", "four"]);
  });
}
```

---

Why?

- When passing an expression to a child component with the '&' binding, the expression doesnt get evaluated until the child component calls it.
- Although the expression gets called by the child component, it gets evaluated on the parent scope.
- This expression has no idea about whats going on in the child component - so it has no idea of the variables/values that are present.
- How does AngularJS get around this? Think of it as AngularJS using the object you pass into the binding (when you call it) to create 'local variables' to evaluate the expression with.

---

So in `PageHeaderComponent`, when you go:

```
$ctrl.getItems({value: $viewValue})
```

Think of AngularJS doing this for `LandingPageComponent`:

```
let value = $viewValue;
$ctrl.getItems(value);
```

**This isn't actually the case, but I think it should help you in understanding why we need to pass an object back (rather than the values directly)**

---

This post does a really good job of describing why we need to deal with Output Events in this way:

http://www.codelord.net/2016/05/13/understanding-angulars-and-binding/